# What is meant by Terminal

Tags: 12.04, lts

New Ubuntu 12.04 LTS user here.  I have downloaded Google Earth, it shows as its downloaded but says it must be operated from a terminal.  Could someone please explain what terminal means in that context.
Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu and AskUbuntu! I would suggest you take a look at some of the resources suggested in [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/q/51566/58950) to familiarize yourself with your new Operating System.

Answer (score 4):

A terminal is where you enter commands to tell the computer what to do. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal for more information. In windows, it is called command prommpt (cmd for short). You can launch Terminal in ubuntu by pressing
`Ctrl + Alt + T`.  If you have never used a terminal before I recommend you go through the [HowToGeek tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/140679/)